# How to format WinLogon\Shell with multiple spaces, quotes, and special characters?

Tags: windows-registry, special-characters

Trying to start a custom application instead of explorer.exe at startup, but can't seem to figure out the proper format to accommodate the extra spaces, quotes, and special characters. Here's what I've tried...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Software\Version 9.02 update 3\startup.exe" /config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Software\Version 9.02 update 3\Configuration\Startup.Configuration.003.xml"

"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\startup.exe\" /config \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\Configuration\\Startup.Configuration.003.xml'""

"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\startup.exe\" \\\\/config \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\Configuration\\Startup.Configuration.003.xml'""
```

Just can't seem to figure it out. Suggestions? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting tripped up by the difference between a registry string value with quotation marks and *the way it appears in a registry export!*

The first version of your command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Software\Version 9.02 update 3\startup.exe" /config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom Software\Version 9.02 update 3\Configuration\Startup.Configuration.003.xml"
```

looks like a working command. So I pasted it into a string value ("TestShell") via regedit. In the registry editor, it looks like this:

[image]

When I export that key, the value looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Dummy]
"TestShell"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\startup.exe\" /config \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Custom Software\\Version 9.02 update 3\\Configuration\\Startup.Configuration.003.xml\""
```

So if you have a command that works from the `Run` dialog or a Command Prompt, copy it to a value in regedit & then export (if you wanted a file to merge on other computers ). No need for you to manually create escaped strings.